# Euler's relation and the energy of a complex exponential signal

Tags: signal, math

I'm having a little hard time understanding the equation:

[image]

Why Euler's relation's square is equal to 1?

I know how to write Euler's equation in terms of sin and cos:

[image]

But when I do the math, the square of this equality is nothing but 1. I can't get rid of from the sin and cos in the equation:
$$(e^{jwt})^2 = cos^2(jwt)+2jcos(jwt)sin(jwt)+j^2sin^2(jwt)$$

$$= cos^2(jwt)-sin^2(jwt)+2jcos(jwt)sin(jwt)$$

I'm probably missing something with the Euler's relation here so I would like to hear what am I missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice, that \$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\$:

$$\left|\exp\left(xi\right)\right|=1\tag1$$

Because:

$$\left|\exp\left(xi\right)\right|=\left|\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)i\right|=\sqrt{\underbrace{\cos^2\left(x\right)+\sin^2\left(x\right)}_{=\space 1}}=\sqrt{1}=1\tag2$$

So, for your integral we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{I}\left(\text{T}_0\right)&=\int\limits_0^{\text{T}_0}\left|\exp\left(\omega_0t\text{j}\right)\right|^2\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\text{T}_0}\left|\cos\left(\omega_0t\right)+\sin\left(\omega_0t\right)\text{j}\right|^2\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\text{T}_0}\left(\sqrt{\underbrace{\cos^2\left(\omega_0t\right)+\sin^2\left(\omega_0t\right)}_{=\space1}}\right)^2\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\text{T}_0}\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{1}\right)^2}_{=\space1}\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\text{T}_0}1\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\left[t\right]_0^{\text{T}_0}\\
\\
&=\text{T}_0-0\\
\\
&=\text{T}_0
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Answer (score 5):

I believe the vertical bars inside the integration denote magnitude. This exponent is a phasor whose magnitude is one and angle is (wt). The square of one is also one.

The magnitude of the phasor (or complex number) is the square root of: the real part squared plus the imaginary part (without j) squared. When you add sin^2 and cos^2, the result is one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes yes, I see what I was missing, I didn't pay attention to the absolute value inside the integration, now it makes sense. I was focused on the square part.